# Extract polygons which touch specified polygon in r

Tags: r, shapefile

I am working with a shapefile containing polygons in r. I am looking to extract a specific polygon  within the shapefile and also the surrounding polygons. i.e. the polygons that directly touch my specified polygon.

Is this possible in r? I have examined the data myself in another GIS software so I can see the ids of these surrounding polygons and extract them manually

```
                   shape_old<-readOGR(dsn=shapefile.shp)
          shape_new<-subset(shape_old, town=="Pleasantville"
```

-but I am hoping there is an automated way of doing this.

I have read about gtouches() but from what I understand this is a test to see if polygons touch, not a way to extract them.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you gave an example data set, like `library(sf); nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))`, and then an example of what you're expected outcome is on this data.

Comment: Apologies! I imported my data using the rgdal package and the command:
 readOGR () so my data was imported like:
shape_old<-readOGR(dsn=shapefile.shp)

Comment: That's still not helpful, we can't see or use your data. If you use the data I supplied in my previous comment then anyone here can help you as it's available to everyone.

Comment: `?sf::st_touches()`